# Is there an interface mechanism for nested enum classes?

Tags: c++, oop, class, inheritance

In C++, pure virtual functions provide the functionality of an interface. That is, any subclasses **must** implement all pure-virtual functions in the base class:

```
class myClass {
    virtual bool implementme() = 0; // MUST be implemented
};

class mySubClass : public myClass {
    bool implementme() {} // REQUIRED
};
```

Is there a similar mechanism for nested (`enum`) `class`es? That is, I'm looking for something like

```
class myClass {
    virtual enum class myEnum = 0; // MUST be implemented
};

class mySubClass : public myClass {
    enum class myEnum {}; // REQUIRED
};
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @DarkFalcon: I want to make absolutely sure that *all* subclasses of `myClass` have an `enum` with the same name. I also want to make absolutely sure that there is no "default" enum, as you would have when just inheriting from (non-virtual) `myClass`.

Comment: @Rody - Does the code compile?

Comment: @EdHeal: nope, obviously not :) Also simpe google searches turned up not much useful.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: I'm asking WHY you want to do this. I understand the concept. I don't understand why you need some other mechanism to enforce this beyond the usual compile errors when you try to reference a name that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Rody - It it does not even compile (just like talking gibberish) why is this going to be a problem? Of course it is POETS day - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POETS_day

Comment: @DarkFalcon: Call the base class `Animal`. Suppose you're working in an environment where you *cannot* assume the default `Animal` has a `Eyeball:LEFT` and `Eyeball::RIGHT`. So, assume `Dog` and `Spider`. I want `Dog` and `Spider` to have `enum class Eyeball`. I want to ensure that all calls to `[Some animal]::Eyeball` will succeed and be intuitive. My managerial approach is then to force implementation of `Eyeballs` during development of each individual `Animal`. We *will not get* compile time errors, because we are not going to write the `Eyecontact` classes, which (might) need `Eyeballs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say that the implementer is not part of your code base (thus not producing a compile error), I must assume you are writing a library, and that the code which uses this enum is in the consumer of the library.

I would recommend that you use [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) as follows:

```
class myClass {
};

template<typename T> class myClassImpl : public myClass {
  static_assert(std::is_enum<typename T::myEnum>::value, "Subclasses of myClassImpl must provide the myEnum enum class");
};

class mySubClass : public myClassImpl<mySubClass> {
    enum class myEnum {};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't make a whole lot of sense. Someone could only have visibility to only the base class (not the derived class) and get back a `myEnum` from the return of some virtual function, where `myEnum` is an incomplete type. There is no mechanism for virtual types of any kind, including enums. Do you really want a virtual table looking up your type anyway?

Comment: I want `myClass` to be an interface, meaning, it cannot be instantated (everyone will have visibility to at least one *derived* class). I also want to be sure that *all* subclasses of `myClass` have an `enum` with the same name, that they did *not* obtain through inheritance from `myClass`.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis You're mistaken about what an interface is. It's perfectly common, outright intended in fact, for you to have a pointer or reference to an interface without visibility to _any_ derived class.

Comment: Regardless of whether I'm using the [correct terminology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(object-oriented_programming)) or not, do you know of a method to force subclasses to implement the `enum` while not getting any default from the base class?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis My response was not about correct terminology. It doesn't matter what kind of base class you have, you can always have one without visibility of a derived class. What you're trying to do isn't allowed. You basically want a run time deduced type. C++ isn't the right language for that kind of magic, it's statically typed.